# Openstack with autopilot, some networking clear up

Tags: networking, juju, maas, cloud, openstack-autopilot

I have some questions about Openstack. I am planning on using Ubuntu and landscape (with autopilot too).

1.) First I installed MAAS and added the nodes to it. Now when issuing the command “sudo openstack-install” I can choose a couple of options, where I choose the landscape option. According to this link: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/clouddocs/installer/en/multi-install.html I can type “openstack-install  --edit-placement”, sadly this does not work for the landscape option. How can I force the installer to use a specific node?

2.) On the requirements for ubuntu autopilot (http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud) it says that I need at least 2 machines with 2 NIC’s. Why 2?

3.) I am aware of the following openstack setup: http://wiki.fi-xifi.eu/wiki/images/e/e5/Openstack_network_arch.png . As mentioned in question 2, I think it has something to do with the different networks that openstack needs. Is it possible for an end-user to make sure that every node has e.g. 4 ports and setup the different networks on different VLAN’s or even different switches?

4.) What does openstack on Ubuntu use right now to devide the different networks (as in the picture from question 3)? Vlans maybe?

5.) As I understand correctly openstack (when deploying a new VM) looks for an Nova instance which has the right amount of hardware to run that instance, but that is IMHO a little to expensive. Sometimes machines can perfectly share the same CPU core as machine. Just like in a normal hypervisor. Is this possible to setup in openstack?

6.) I was planning on using some 10 gbit/s cards for the data between the storage node and the KVM compute nodes. Is it possible to use the 10 gbit/s cards when the compute node and the storage node talk to eachother and use the “normal” 1gbit/s card for e.g. management or connecting with other services?

7.) In the same link as in question 2, it says that for the requirements it is advised to use 2 disks in all machines. Why? I guess that the first is used for the ubuntu install for that node and the second one for example the VM data is storage? If that is true can I say that I use one small SSD for the system itself and a bigger one for the VM’s? How can I tell openstack which one to use for what?

Answer (score 0):

Answer(s):

1.) Can be accomplished by typing:

JUJU_BOOTSTRAP_TO=host.maas sudo -E openstack-install

(Thanks to "stokachu" from IRC)

5.) This is an option that is set in the scheduler of Openstack and can be changed in the nova.conf file on the compute nodes. (**NOT YET TESTED**)